# How to read O.T.P message for verification in Oreo?

Tags: android, api, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I tried almost everything using broadcast. But i am not able to get OTP message . It is working fine with lower version but not in **`Oreo`** version

Comment: Asking for allowing permission to read SMS or not at run time?

Comment: yes i ask it ..but still it is not working

Comment: post your source code

Comment: Try this: http://swarajsaaj.github.io/posts/reading-sms-automatically-otp-verification-android

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.